# LinkedIn official 'share' button functionality does not appear to work

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, share, data-uri

Trying to embed the HTML for this official 'share' snippet from linkedin in to my blog.

The specification is here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin

The markup for which reads like this

`<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>`

`<script type="IN/Share" data-url="https://www.linkedin.com"></script>`

According to linkedin, the data-url value can be updated to pull the relevant thumbnail and information in to the share snippet. Currently, i can not make this work. Modifying the data-url does nothing and no matter what data i include there it simply pulls one of the root favicon images and posts the general metadata header from my index ('www.mywebsite.com' instead of 'www.mywwebsite.com/blog/post.html')

I've tested this with other URLs and the behaviour varies although is not correct for any i have tested. Attempting to share an article from the BBC site for example pulls a thumbnail and plasters this within an iframe, no text.

I had thought this might be something to do with open graph data but updating that in the file header does nothing.

Linkedin provide zero assistance in any attempts at contacting their support, just point at 'plugins' above and close the case immediately.

I'm putting this out in the hopes that someone in the StackOverflow community may have tackled this one before.

If this is in the wrong place, well, please point in the right directio. I can either delete and repost or relocate if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with getting the right meta-data to show for your site, even though you know you changed it, then it *could be* a caching issue.  Take a look at the official documentation, [LinkedIn.com: How to clear Linkedin link preview cache?](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-clear-linkedin-link-preview-cache-ananda-kannan-p/)...

> After updating your website with perfect preview content and image, if you try sharing your website link you will still see old preview content and image. ***That's because LinkedIn caches link preview content for 7 days.***

Want to clear the cache?  Two ways...

Try out the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com).  When you use the inspector, this typically refreshes the cache, as this is a pretty good indicator to LinkedIn that someone is dev'ing and cache should be cleared.  But it's useful in other ways, too, for instance, testing on stackoverflow.com, I know how exactly the Title is generated, because it tells me precisely...

> Title
>
> Note: We used the value from the provided Open Graph tag on the page.

The second way to clear cache: If you are testing `example.com`, try testing out `example.com?test=1`.  The URL is different, and that's enough for a new preview to be generated.

Comment: yes, i did all of this eventually, you are right thanks -

the linkedin 'post inspector' does not work consistently, unfortunately - we have tried to implement it in two instances running, it only functions correctly on the first. thereafter fails in modern browsers FF, Chome, Edge.